# node.js rerun script on specific event

Tags: node.js, nodegit

I'm **not** looking for a file watcher like [nodemon](https://nodemon.io/)

I have the following scenario:
I'm running a script `script.js` in `nodeJS`, In some cases I have to switch to a different `git` branch (I know how to do this part).
After the `git` branch is switched, I would like to exit the current run and reload `script.js` again.

How do I cause `nodeJS` to reload and run the same script again?
Do I need to start another process and exit the current one?

Comment: Well, in order to deal with `git` repos in `NodeJS` you can use `nodegit` module. However in order to trigger an event and stop the running `NodeJS` process and restart with new process, you might need to create a Shell script and use it to automate this operation. One example can be seen here: https://medium.com/@aunnnn/automate-digitalocean-deployment-for-node-js-with-git-and-pm2-67a3cfa7a02b